# Checking characters

Tags: c++, string, compare

How do I check a character array? For example I am making a program which ask me to input a password, lets say **ZEZO**, then it checks if it's correct and then prints "**hello zezo**". I'm currently using turbo c++ for school stuff. I have an example program:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    char * zezo;
    zezo = "Zezo";

    cout<<"Hello "<<zezo;
}
```

I just need to know how to get the word checking.

Answer (score 5):

Use a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of a `char*` and then use either `operator ==` or `compare` to check the string.

Answer (score 3):

`iostream.h` and `conio.h`? `void main`? Find new learning material, ASAP, because whatever you're learning from is embarrassingly bad.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
    if (s == "Zezo")
        // Cool
    else
        // Not cool 
}
```

Comment: Mind giving some better and easy example software's?

Comment: @DotNetZeZo he's saying the headers are wrong and the signature of main is invalid. You should get a better book. (if a professor gave you this code and said it was C++, may God have mercy on your soul)

Comment: You can get Clang 3.2, MinGW 4.7.2 or Visual Studio 2012 Express for free. They are all compilers from this *century* and far superior.

Answer (score 0):

[strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/)

```
bool matches = strcmp(zezo, "ZEZO") == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for strcmp and better for std::string and related functions